# Unique Lowest Common Ancestor

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

It is well known that in a tree two nodes x,y always have a unique lowest common ancestor LCA(x,y). If we think of the tree as directed with all edges going up and define the ancestors of node A(x) to be all the nodes reachable from x, then we could define the  LCA(x,y) to be any minimal element of the intersection of A(x) and A(y).  It is well known that for trees this is unique while for general DAGs it may not be; alternatively it may not exist.

I'm interested in generalizations where we start with a tree and then add directed edges such that the resulting graph is still a DAG; however, I want to require that it still has unique LCAs.  Is there a characterization of such graphs? In particular, I'd like to know how many there are as a function of the number of nodes.

Comment: Very similar to semilattice, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice .

Comment: Good point. I'd forgotten to add that. The problem is that I am trying to understand it from a graph perspective and have not been able to find much information about that, but would appreciate any pointers.